# How to conditionally hide a column in rtf template when 0 value

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

I need to hide the whole column in the rtf template when the value is equal to '0' then it needs to be shown when the value is greater than '0'

I have tried the ff. But none of them worked.
Sol#1
Column Header
<if@column:COLUMNAME="0"?>

Cell
<if@column:../../COLUMNAME="0"?>

Sol#2
Column Header
<if@column:contains(COLUMNAME, '0')?>COLUMNHEADERNAME>

Cell
<if@cell:contains(COLUMNAME, '0')?>

Sol#3
Column Header
<if@column:/COLUMNAME/@type="PRIVATE"?>

Cell
<if@column:/COLUMNAME/@type="PRIVATE"?>

Here' sample template output, the highlighted in yellow should be hided.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdOeK.png)

Comment: `<if@column:X="0"?>` should show the column when X is zero, you'll have to negate that statement for your requirement. `<if@column:X != "0"?>`

Comment: If that doesn't work, please provide sample xml data and template.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Column:

- you should put the If condition for the column label and for the column value
  1.Place your cursor infront of the label
  2.Click "Conditional Region" on BI Publisher Tab
  3.Clik "Advanced" tab on Dialog window
  4.Write your condition:

```xml
<?if@column:YOUR_COLUMN>0?>
```

5. Click OK - There wil be "C" and "EC" marks

- If you select and doubleclick on "C" you should see your condition on BI Publisher Properties dialog
- If "EC" is in next column it should work anyway but I like to cut - paste it at the end of label and of value like in the picture

6. Do the same for your column value
   [image]

More about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/bip/BIPRD/GUID-04477E49-F671-4BF1-8353-06A7CDEAD2CC.htm#BIPRD2483) (find "@column" on page)
Regards...
**Addition**:
with your xml data - the outcome depends on your deffinition of groups. Below find two different tables based on same data with group definitions.

[image]
... here is the result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this it worked. But now I used dynamic data column, but the generated output  has blank fields and the table become broken.  This is my sample xml data structure.

Comment: 1ST COLUMN HEADER
Value Date <?horizontal-break-table:1?> 
1st field
for each 
<?for-each-group@section:G_ELEMENT_VALUES;./VALUE_DATE?><?variable@incontext:VAL;VALUE_DATE?>
VALUE_DATE <?VALUE_DATE?>

Comment: 2ND COLUMN HEADER
for each <?for-each-group@column:G_ELEMENT_VALUES;./ELEMENT_NAME?> 
ELEMENT_NAME <?ELEMENT_NAME?> 
end for-each

Comment: 2ND FIELD
for each 
<?for-each-group@cell:current-group();./ELEMENT_NAME?><?if:not(ELEMENT_NAME)?> 0<?end if?> 

RESULT_VALUE
 <?sum(current-group()//RESULT_VALUE)?> 
end for-each
 end for-each

Comment: the above rtf code, worked but the table became broken (or blank fields with table broken) in case the element name is not present

Comment: It is hard to tell without sample xml, rtf coding and result, but, it seems like you have to handle the existance of the node ELEMENT_NAME and/or the value of it. The code "if:not(ELEMENT_NAME)?> 0<?end if?>" means if ELEMENT_NAME is not greater than 0 then .... something - in this case (if I got it right) the NULL or '' empty string or non existing ELEMENT_NAME is not greater than 0. Make sure that there is an ELEMENT_NAME present and then handle the value of it.

Comment: Check this https://gist.github.com/ijy/6572634

Comment: This is the sample xml result

Comment: https://github.com/Feyifey/Xml-sample/blob/main/Sample%20actual%20xml